# Doctrine2 order by count

Tags: mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I've found plenty of answers to this question, but i'm stuck right now with my query and i can't find out what i'm doing wrong.

This is my Query:

```
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t', 'count(t.views) AS HIDDEN count');
    $qb->addOrderBy('count', 'DESC');
    $qb->groupBy('t.id');

    return $qb->getQuery();
```

The created query looks like this:

```
SELECT t, count(t.views) AS HIDDEN count FROM Bundle\Entity\Turn t GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY count DESC
```

I'm using Doctrine2 within Symfony2 the created Query will be given to the Pagerfanta Bundle.

If i'm missing any information i need to provide just ask in the comments.

The Query Exception i'm getting is the following:

`Query Exception: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 95: Error: Expected end of string, got '('`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an alias in an order by clause.

You may then try

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t, count(t.views) AS myCount');
$qb->addOrderBy('myCount', 'DESC');
```

or if you don't need the count in your results, but just for the order

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t');
$qb->addOrderBy('count(t.views)', 'DESC');
```

I think you can even do it with AS HIDDEN, just removing the useless quotes

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
        ->select('t, count(t.views) AS HIDDEN myCount');
$qb->addOrderBy('myCount', 'DESC');
```

Comment: I tried it out, my generated Query looks like this now `SELECT t FROM Mysailinglog\Bundle\MysailinglogBundle\Entity\Turn t GROUP BY t.id ORDER BY count(t.views) DESC` and i'm getting this Query Exception: `[Syntax Error] line 0, col 95: Error: Expected end of string, got '('`

Comment: Did you try third version ?

Comment: Well, i did not sleep well this night, i messed up the column. View is already a count, so counting a count will always give 1 back :D I'm a bit ashamed of myself, BUT i tried i out with a correct field and it's working perfectly! Thanks!